# Real life examples of negative weight edges in graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am unable to relate to any real life examples of negative weight edges in graphs.  Distances between cities cannot be negative.  Time taken to travel from one point to another cannot be negative.  Data transfer rates cannot be negative.  I am just blanking out while thinking of negative weight edges in graphs.

---

Can we have a list of say 6 or 7 real-life examples where negative weights make intuitive sense?

Comment: This might help: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14248/what-is-the-significance-of-negative-weight-edges-in-a-graph

Comment: Weight can represent the cost of doing something, measured in money/energy. Negative costs means that you earn money/energy instead of losing it.